# SQL select order by decimal precision desc

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I'm interested in finding the most precise decimal values in a database field.  I'd like to be able to sort results by descending precision.  Is this possible?

e.g.

10.1781253
12345.12435
89.763
1.1
2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to order by the substring of the part after any dot. This is going to be a DB specific SQL query and since you didn't mention which one you're using I can't give a detailed SQL example.

Comment: I was hoping for vanilla SQL, but the DBMS is Oracle.

Comment: Sorry, never used it extensively. I can only for MySQL, PostegreSQL and DB2 tell from head how to do it. But I think you already know/understand where to look for the solution. Good luck.