# In Vertica SQL, how do I order by decimal precision?

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a column with two types of numbers. One is rounded to one decimal place, and the other is not rounded and hence has very high decimal precision. I would like to sort by these types in order to separate the data.

The data looks like this:

```
column
------
12.8255089150483
12.8922181755615
12179.7
13.2379805518594
14612.2
15.3011111458778
```

I would like it to look something like this:

```
column
------
12179.7
14612.2
12.8255089150483
12.8922181755615
13.2379805518594
15.3011111458778
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is difficult to do precisely, because (presumably) the number is a floating point.

For your example, the following should work:

```
order by (case when cast(col as decimal(20, 1)) = cast(col as decimal(20, 10)
               then 1 else 2
          end)
```

This converts the numbers to fixed point format, one with one decimal place and one with 10.  If they are the same, then we put them first in the sort order.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank Gordon for his clever answer. Here is what I ended up with that worked for me:

```
select rtp::varchar as rtp2
from table
order by (
    case when split_part(ifnull(rtp,0)::varchar,'.',2) = ''
    then 0 
    else split_part(ifnull(rtp,0)::varchar,'.',2)::int
    end) desc
limit 100
;
```

As you can see, I also had some null values that I needed to deal with.

I got a hint for this from here:
[SQL select order by decimal precision desc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448712/sql-select-order-by-decimal-precision-desc)

Answer (score 0):

I see we have two excellent answers already. Adding a third possibility:

```
select rtp from t1 order by ( 10*rtp - floor(rtp*10) ) ;
```

You can add DESC to the ORDER BY if you want the numbers with a single decimal place at the end...